# Displaying data by only month and year in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, analytics

I have a set of data, I want to display the transactions per-month for the last 12 months grouped and ordered by month.

My Code is currently:

```
SELECT
to_char(orderdate, 'MM-YYYY') AS MONTH_AND_YEAR
,SUM(VALUE) AS TOTAL_SALES
,ROUND(AVG(VALUE),2) AS AVERAGE_SALE_VALUE
,MIN(VALUE) AS MINIMUM_SALE_VALUE
,MAX(VALUE) AS MAXIMUM_SALES_VALUE
FROM ORDER_TABLE
WHERE OrderDate >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC(SYSDATE), -12 )
GROUP BY to_char(orderdate, 'MM-YYYY')
ORDER BY to_char(orderdate, 'MM-YYYY') DESC;
```

but is returning :

### MONTH_AND_YEAR

12-2021
12-2020
11-2021
11-2020
10-2021
10-2020
09-2021
09-2020
08-2021
08-2020
07-2020
06-2020
05-2021
05-2020
04-2021
04-2020
03-2021
03-2020
02-2020
01-2021
01-2020

helpful:

| MAX(ORDERDATE) | MIN(ORDERDATE) |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 |

Thank you in advances for you help and advice

Comment: For dates it is much more efficient to group and order by `trunc(orderdate, 'mm')` - don't involve strings here. Then, in `select` you will still need to use `to_char`, but like this: `select to_char(trunc(orderdate, 'mm'), 'mm-yyyy'), ....` (because you must reference a GROUP BY expression, which in this case is the `trunc(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
ORDER BY MIN(orderdate) DESC;
```

Ordering by a string representation starting with the month is not going to produce the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `order by TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(orderdate,'MM'))` extract the month as a number and then use it to order by.

Comment: This will still group together the same month from both years (Jan 2020, Jan 2021, Feb 2020, Feb 2021, ...) - exactly what the OP is doing now, and what he does **not** want. For your own use, note that `extract(month from orderdate)` is a much simpler way to do what you were doing with `to_number(........)`. Anyway - this answer is not helpful.